# Mongoose CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Post"

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN stack project where a user can add a post, edit and delete them. But after performing the methods required, the posts are not getting deleted and I face an error. I am new to MEAN stack.

**posts.service.ts**

```
getPosts() {
 this.http.get<{ message: string, posts: any }>('http://localhost:3300/api/posts')
 .pipe(
   map((postData) => {
     return postData.posts.map(post=>{
       return{
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content,
      id: post._id
    }
     })
    }))
  .subscribe((transformedPosts)=>{
  this.posts = transformedPosts; 
  this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts])  //updating the posts so that it is available to the rest of the app
   })
  }
getUpdatedPostsListener(){
   return this.postsUpdated.asObservable()
}
  
addPosts(id: any, title: string, content: string) {
  const post: PostModel = {
    id: id,
    title: title,
    content: content
  }
  this.http.post<{ message: string }>('http://localhost:3300/api/posts', post).subscribe((responseData)=>{
    console.log(responseData.message);
  })
  this.posts.push(post);
  this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
}

deletePosts(postId: string){
  this.http.delete('http://localhost:3300/api/posts/' + postId)
  .subscribe(()=>{
    const updatedPosts = this.posts.filter(post => post.id! == postId);
    this.posts = updatedPosts;
    this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
  })
}
```

**app.js**

```
  app.delete('/api/posts/:id', (req, res, next) => {
   Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(result => {
       console.log(result);
       res.status(200).json({
           message: 'Post deleted successfully!'
       })
   })
   .catch(err => {
       console.log('error: ', err);
   })
    
})
```

**posts.components.ts**

```
    onDelete(postId: string){
    this.postsService.deletePosts(postId);
  }
```

**posts.component.html**

```
 <mat-action-row>
                <button color="primary" mat-raised-button>Edit</button>
                <button color="warn" mat-raised-button (click)="onDelete(post.id)">Delete</button>
            </mat-action-row>
```

**post-models.js (for the backend)**

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    content: { type: String, required: true }
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

**This is the error that I face everytime I try to delete any post:-**

> error:  CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at
> path "_id" for model "Post"
> at model.Query.exec (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4358:21)
> at model.Query.Query.then (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4452:15)
> at E:\Angular\KUSpace\backend\app.js:48:43
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at param (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
> at param (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
> at Function.process_params (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
> at next (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at E:\Angular\KUSpace\backend\app.js:22:5
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at trim_prefix (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
> at E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7 {
> messageFormat: undefined,   stringValue: '"undefined"',   kind:
> 'ObjectId',   value: 'undefined',   path: '_id',   reason: Error:
> Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of
> 24 hex characters
> at new ObjectID (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
> at castObjectId (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
> at ObjectId.cast (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:279:12)
> at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1088:12)
> at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1523:15)
> at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1513:15)
> at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1490:20)
> at cast (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:331:32)
> at model.Query.Query.cast (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4763:12)
> at model.Query.Query._castConditions (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1841:10)
> at model.Query. (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2722:8)
> at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _deleteOne] (E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
> at E:\Angular\KUSpace\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)         }

Comment: Have you checked the called url in the browser inspectors network tab. Does it have the correct id in the path?

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:3300/api/posts/null

This is what it shows when I click on the delete button

Comment: Ok, so the issue is in your frontend code. How does the object structure look like when logging it to the console in your angular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the `AddPosts` method in the `post.service.ts`, the issue was solved

**post.service.ts**

```
addPosts(title: string, content: string) {
  const post: PostModel = {
    id: null,
    title: title,
    content: content
  }
  this.http.post<{ message: string , postId: string }>('http://localhost:3300/api/posts', post).subscribe((responseData)=>{
    console.log(responseData.message);
    post.id = responseData.postId;
    this.posts.push(post);
  this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);

  })
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer:

If you don't want to deal with `ObjectId` and the transformations between `ObjectId` and `String`, and between `id` and `_id`.

You could use `_id` field backend and frontend. Also, to save it in the backend as a `String` add the following line to your schema:

```
_id: { type: String, required: true }
```

And now when you create a new post you make it like this:

```
  const post: PostModel = {
     _id: _id,
     title: title,
     content: content
   }
```

Then you could use [bson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson) to generate new ObjectId to pass it to the backend.

```
import { ObjectID } from 'bson';

{ _id: new ObjectID().toHexString() }
```